# document.getSelection doesn't return carriage returns in the resulting string in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm trying to use the javascript method document.getSelection() to retrieve the selected text in a Web page.
I've noticed that in Mozilla Firefox, this method returns the string without '\r' nor '\n' characters, while in the other browsers the returned string contains these characters.

This is how I retrieve the selected text:

```
    function getSelText() {
       var str = "";
       if (document.getSelection) {
          str = document.getSelection();
       } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
          var range = document.selection.createRange();
          str = range.text;
       } else {
          str = "Sorry, selection is not available with your browser.";
       }
       var tmp = new String(str);
       var regex = new RegExp("'", 'g');
       str = tmp.replace(regex, "&apos;");
       return str;
    }
```

Am I missing anything?

Thank you very much!

Best

cghersi

Comment: Are you sure? It works on my Nightly http://jsfiddle.net/xkUcF/

Comment: Yes, I double-checked just now. Moreover, I cannot understand how to use jsfiddle.net

Comment: The fiddle that I linked is set to use the `no wrap (body)` setting so whatever you paste in the JavaScript section will execute after the HTML has rendered. You can then Run the fiddle to check the output and Save/Update it to share with others.